# Very simple shopping cart, remove button

Tags: php, html, mysql, shopping-cart

I'm writing sales software that will be walking through a set of pages and on certain pages there are items listed to sell and when you click buy it basically just passes a hidden variable to the next page to be set as a session variable, and then when you get to the end it call gets reported to a database.

However my employer wanted me to include a shopping cart, and this shopping cart should display the item name, sku, and price of whatever you're buying, as well as a remove button so the person doing the script doesn't need to go back through the entire thing to remove one item.

At the moment I have the cart set to display everything, which was fairly simple. But I can't figure out how to get the remove button to work. Here is the code for the shopping cart:

```php
$total = 0;
//TEST CODE:
$_SESSION['itemname-addon'] = "Test addon";
$_SESSION ['price-addon'] = 10.00;
$_SESSION ['sku-addon'] = "1234h";

$_SESSION['itemname-addon1'] = "Test addon1";
$_SESSION ['price-addon1'] = 99.90;
$_SESSION ['sku-addon1'] = "1111";

$_SESSION['itemname-addon2'] = "Test addon2";
$_SESSION ['price-addon2'] = 19.10;
$_SESSION ['sku-addon2'] = "123";
//end test code
    
$items = Array
(
    "0"=> Array
    (
      "name" => $_SESSION['itemname-mo'],
      "price" => $_SESSION ['price-mo'],
      "sku" => $_SESSION ['sku-mo']
    ),
    "1" => Array
    (
      "name" => $_SESSION['itemname-addon'],
      "price" => $_SESSION ['price-addon'],
      "sku" => $_SESSION ['sku-addon']
    ),
    "2" => Array
    (
      "name" => $_SESSION['itemname-addon1'],
      "price" => $_SESSION ['price-addon1'],
      "sku" => $_SESSION ['sku-addon1']
    ),
    "3" => Array
    (
      "name" => $_SESSION['itemname-addon2'],
      "price" => $_SESSION ['price-addon2'],
      "sku" => $_SESSION ['sku-addon2']
    )
    
  );

$a_length = count($items);

for($x = 0; $x<$a_length; $x++){
$total +=$items[$x]['price']; 
}
$formattedtotal = number_format($total,2,'.','');
for($i = 0; $i < $a_length; $i++){
$name = $items[$i]['name'];
$price = $items[$i]['price'];
$sku = $items[$i]['sku'];
displaycart($name,$price,$sku);
}
echo "<br />
<b>Sub Total:</b> 
$$formattedtotal";
  
  function displaycart($name,$price,$sku){
    
    if($name != null || $price != null || $sku != null){
    
    if ($name == "no sale" || $price == "no sale" || $sku == "no sale"){
    echo ""; 
    }
    else{
      $formattedprice = number_format($price,2,'.','');
      echo "$name: $$formattedprice ($sku)";
      echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">";
      echo "<button type=\"submit\" />Remove</button><br />";
      echo "</form>";
    }
    
    }
  }
```

So at this point I'm not sure where to go from here for the remove button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arrays on session variables so you could change your format to

```
$_SESSION[items][] = ("name"=>$name, "sku"=>$sku, "price"->$price)
```

in your `function displaycart()` add the element

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='delete_sku' value='$sku'>\n";
```

then when you delete you simply:

```
$delete_sku = $_POST[delete_sku]; // the posted ID sent from delete form
$i = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION[items] as $item) {
    if ($item['sku'] == $delete_sku) {
        unset ($_SESSION[$i]);  // remove the item from the session array
    }
    $i++;
}
print_r ($_SESSION);
```